# dir - List all folders except some

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to make a Windows batch file to show installed Half Life 1 mods.

Installed mods have their own folder in the directory where hl.exe is, eg `cstrike` or `SvenCoop`.

But there are also a few folders in that same directory that are part of the hl1 engine: `bin`, `gldrv`, `platform`, `relists`, and `valve`.

I'd like to do a `dir` that lists all the folders in that directory except those 5 folders that are part of the hl1 engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    set show=yes
    for %%a in (bin gldrv platform relists valve) do if %%d == %%a set show=no
    if !show! == yes dir %%d
)
```