# Remove all files and directories except one directory

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, windows-console

I want to use windows command line to remove all files and directories except one, the folder ".svn".
I tried doing it like this, in two steps (my working directory is the folder that I want to clean):

1. First remove all directories with the exception of ".svn": `dir /B /A:D | findstr /V ".svn" | rmdir /Q`
2. Remove all files: `del * /F /Q`

Step 2 is OK, but for step 1 I get an "The syntax of the command is incorrect." error. Thrown by the `rmdir`cmd. Does anybody know how to do this OK: delete all directories except one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008567/windows-batch-script-to-delete-everything-in-a-folder-except-one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281289/dir-list-all-folders-except-some

Comment: So you redirect the dir-output to findstr? Yuck! What do you try to accomplish with the second Pipe after Findstr? This cannot work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /B /A:D') do if ["%i"] neq [".svn"] rd "%i" /f /q
```

**explanation**

the for-loop enumerates the output of the dir-command. you must specify tokens=* in case there are spaced in the directory name.

The square brackets and double quotes around the if-parameters is an old trick to avoid problems if the argument ever gets nothing (or blank) or contains blanks

*Dont forget to double the %-signs if you want to put this in a cmd-file*